# Javascript function inside HTML input box

Tags: javascript, html

OK, new to JS, but I have a HTML form with a input box. This input box value needs to be = to a JavaScript function I wrote and I can't get it to work.

In the head I have the location of my js file. Basically, I want to have the input box value = the JavaScript function.

`<script src="js/functions.js"></script>`

The HTML input box

```
<input type="text" name="date" id= "date" value= "" class="inputBox"
 disabled />
```

The JavaScript function

```
function dateToday{
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

document.write(today);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use document.getElementById("date").value to set the value of the input.
Also "function dateToday{" need to be changed to "function dateToday(){"

```js
function dateToday() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

  document.write(today);
  document.getElementById("date").value = today;
}

dateToday();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" class="inputBox" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
// Place this code at the end of the document body
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("date").value = dateToday();    
};
</script>
</body>
```

And change **document.write(today);** to **return today;**

You may want to look into the *date* input type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

You can do document.getElementById("date").value = dateToday() as mentioned by user2182349 and also make sure to add

return today;

in your function dateToday().

Comment: But where would I put the document.getelement code?

Comment: You can use jquery and put do document.getelement inside document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        document.getElementById("date").value = dateToday()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for a few changes here and there nothing major. Check the following code.

```js
function dateToday() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

  return today;
}

document.getElementById("date").value = dateToday();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" class="inputBox" disabled/>
```